# Is ZTE Blade compatible with wifi direct?

Tags: zte-blade, wifi-direct

I've installed Android 4.1.2 on the ZTE Blade (Sapo A5) and i would like to know if ZTE Blade is compatible with wifi direct?? Does wifi direct have any hardware requirement?

Comment: Depends on the hardware driver capabilities for the ar6000 chipset. This question should rather be directed at [Modaco](http://www.modaco.com/forum/488-zte-blade-libra-roms-rom-customisation/) and ask in there. Is this one of Konstat's builds?

Comment: Yes it is: gapps-jb-20121017-KonstaKANG.zip
Thanks for the insight

Comment: Well, post it there and someone is bound to answer about this :) Also check the change log/release notes or something there.. :)